# PHP Loop Implementation

Tags: php, loops

I'm working on a script that requests Invoices from an online service - 100 invoices are returned at a time. I've got the basic request working to return the first 100 invoices and loop through the results. Here's my current code:

```
// set pagination to page 1
$page = 1;

// Request Invoices
$response = $XeroOAuth->request('GET', $XeroOAuth->url('Invoices', 'core'), array( 'page' => $page ));


    if ($XeroOAuth->response['code'] == 200) {

        // Parse Invoices
        $invoices = $XeroOAuth->parseResponse($XeroOAuth->response['response'], $XeroOAuth->response['format']);

        // Get total found invoices
        $totalInvoices = count($invoices->Invoices[0]);


        // Loop through found invoices 
        if ($totalInvoices > 0) {

            foreach ($invoices->Invoices->Invoice as $invoice) {
                $invoiceNumber = $invoice->InvoiceNumber;
                // Process Invoice as required
            } 

        }

    } else {

        // Request Error
    }
```

I need to extend this as follows:

- if 100 invoices were returned I need to increment $page by 1 and then perform another request to get the 2nd page of invoices and process those
- continue this until the total number of invoices returned for the last request is less than 100 then exit after that

I can't get the logic correct here to extend this with another loop to continue the requests until it gets less than 100 invoices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php

$breakFlag = 0;

// set pagination to page 1
$page = 1;

do {

    // Request Invoices
    $response = $XeroOAuth->request('GET', $XeroOAuth->url('Invoices', 'core'), array( 'page' => $page ));

    if ($XeroOAuth->response['code'] == 200) {

        // Parse Invoices
        $invoices = $XeroOAuth->parseResponse($XeroOAuth->response['response'], $XeroOAuth->response['format']);

        // Get total found invoices
        $totalInvoices = count($invoices->Invoices[0]);

        if ($totalInvoices < 100) {
            $breakFlag = 1;
        }

        // Loop through found invoices 
        if ($totalInvoices > 0) {

            foreach ($invoices->Invoices->Invoice as $invoice) {
                $invoiceNumber = $invoice->InvoiceNumber;
                // Process Invoice as required
            } 

        }

        $page += 1;

    } else {

        // Request Error
    } 
} while($breakFlag == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd wrap the code you have in a function and then invoke it from within itself for as long as you need to.

```
fetchInvoices(1);

function fetchInvoices($page) {
    // Request Invoices
    $response = $XeroOAuth->request('GET', $XeroOAuth->url('Invoices', 'core'), array( 'page' => $page ));

    if ($XeroOAuth->response['code'] == 200) {

        // Parse Invoices
        $invoices = $XeroOAuth->parseResponse($XeroOAuth->response['response'], $XeroOAuth->response['format']);

        // Get total found invoices
    $totalInvoices = count($invoices->Invoices[0]);


        // Loop through found invoices 
        if ($totalInvoices > 0) {

            foreach ($invoices->Invoices->Invoice as $invoice) {
                $invoiceNumber = $invoice->InvoiceNumber;
                // Process Invoice as required
            } 
        }

        if($totalInvoices == 100) {
            fetchInvoices($page + 1)
        }
    } else {

        // Request Error
    }
}
```